# unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a very simple Spring Boot Application with few basic dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.order.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>OrderService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OrderService</name>
    <description>Order Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

The Maven is able to download all the dependencies except for Eureka Client dependency.
I get the below exception:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.0-rc.4

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.0-rc.4
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$3(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:pom:2.0.0-rc.4 from/to netflix-candidates (https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:pom:2.0.0-rc.4 from/to netflix-candidates (https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:889)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:659)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:107)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:215)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:161)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.getResponse(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:655)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:481)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:915)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:331)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383)
    ... 87 more
    pom.xml /OrderService   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Until few days back, it was working fine but now its not working. I believe this is caused by some network issue but when I open the URL https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates on browser, I get the page which asks to login to JFrog page (hopefully its uploaded here). I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

Just to share, I have added the certificate of the page in Java 19 security/cacerts following this answer but its not helpful:
["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Any insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install SSL certificate of **https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates** in Java TrustStore (cacerts). Please follow these steps and try again.

1. Open URL **https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates** and Extract the SSL certificate then save it to your local.

[image]

2. Go to your java_home\...\lib\security and run this command

```
keytool -importcert -file <Path to certficate> -keystore cacerts -alias "Alias"
```

**password - changeit**

3. Go to project root and run this command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Comment: Hi Rohit - I shared I have already followed the mentioned steps. Please check the link in the post. Secondly, Java 19 doesnt have JRE package as you mentioned "java_home\jre\lib\security". The path is: \jdk-19.0.1\lib\security. Here's the command I ran again:
keytool -importcert -file "..\Documents\artifacts-oss.netflix.net.crt" -keystore cacerts -alias "Alias"
Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
Certificate already exists in keystore under alias <netflix>

Comment: Ok is certificate installed successfully in cacerts?

Comment: Can you please verify this by using this command keytool -list -keystore cacerts -alias "alias"

Comment: I get this:Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
alias, Dec 14, 2022, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): F6:1E:A2:0A:72:FA:7F:25:BD:CB:F4:22:0A:83:02:66:79:06:80:A6:89:6B:D8:61:30:99:39:F3:0C:F5:4F:1E

Comment: ok then certificate is installed, Can you close existing session of CMD or IDE and try again mvn clean package

Comment: Yeah I stated I have done this, nothing is helping.

Comment: looks the certificate added in cacerts in not correct. You added root certificate or child certificate?

Comment: We just have the option to export the certificate on browser. There's no option that talks about root or child.

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshot of root certificate. Can you please install this and try again.

Comment: Yes this helped finally! The catch is we have to select the root certificate and then configure.

Comment: Great, if my answer helps request you to please accept it so that it helps others as well.